# Преобразовать разные форматы дат в одном Excel столбце в datetime

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Уважаемые друзья. У меня есть очень "сложная" задача. Я не знаю как ее решить.

Есть в Excel столбец с датами. Все ячейки столбца разные: Дата, Число, Текст и т.д. Каждую ячейку заполняли разные люди. В столбце где-то около 300 тысяч ячеек (строк).

Я загружаю этот файл в Jupyter, с помощью Pandas:

```
pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx',header=0,dtype = str)
```

Задача, с которой не могу справиться: как преобразовать каждую строку в один тип данных `Дата`? А если преобразовать не удалось, то оставить строкой.

Если более точно:

Например, в Excel ячейка имеет числовое значение `43123` преобразовать в Дату, то это будет `23.01.2018`.

Как в Python выполнить именно такой преобразование?

Всем, кто ответит буду благодарен до глубины души!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

def get_excel_date(col):
    res = pd.to_datetime(col, errors='coerce')
    mask = res.isna()
    res.loc[mask] = pd.to_timedelta(col[mask].astype('float'), unit='d') + dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    return res
```

---

```
In [20]: s = pd.Series(['2018-10-31 23:44:59.996000', '43123', '43511.65625',
                        '13.01.2010T12:12:12', '2019/07/10 23:59:59.123456'])

In [21]: get_excel_date(s)
Out[21]:
0   2018-10-31 23:44:59.996000
1   2018-01-23 00:00:00.000000
2   2019-02-15 15:45:00.000000
3   2010-01-13 12:12:12.000000
4   2019-07-10 23:59:59.123456
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

**PS** [почему разработчики Excel использовали `30.12.1899` в качестве начала эпохи?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev)

Comment: ООООООООООгромное спасибо за ответ. Завтра буду тестировать. Мой сон будет отличным благодаря вашему ответу

Comment: @Евгений, был рад помочь )

Comment: Не смог уснуть. Работает у меня код )))))))))) И про "Начало эпохи" тоже отличная ссылка. А можно попросить Вас помочь сделать один маленький шаг -- если в Series добавить например `43123...`, то код вылетает в ошибку. Можно такие строки просто не удалять, а оставлять в  Series. Или тут можно просто заменить параметром errors='coerce' на errors='ignore'?

Comment: я допер вроде. Надо чуть переделать res.loc[mask]

Comment: @Евгений, можно явно преобразовать столбец в строку и уже потом вызывать функцию...